# Closing Gap Between Divs

Tags: css, positioning

Here's my test site for a new food festival:

http://aksarbenribfest.bugs3.com/public_html/#!/page_home

I managed to move the cartoon logo on the front page closer to the menu arrows on the top of each page, but can't get the remaining pages to 'move up' the page.

I want to eliminate the gap between the column titles (Thursday, Friday & Saturday for example on the 'Music' page) and the bottom of the arrow menu buttons.

Since I'm modifying a template, any other help and hints are definitely appreciated - before I get to too far into it!

Answer (score 0):

If I change the `top` style on your `content` section, I think that achieves what you are looking for:

[image]

([Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tt5Cw.png))

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the inline-style in this line:

```
  <section id="content" style="top: 210px;">
```

just change the top-value to something smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You have CSS on a section element like:

```
 <section id="content" style="top: 210px;">
```

Try reducing that to about 100px.

Answer (score 0):

Delete from `#content > ul > li` `top: 75px`
then add `#content #page_home { top: 75px }`

Comment: After a little fiddling to correct the home page image placement, this fix seems to work the best!  THANKS!  http://aksarbenribfest.bugs3.com/public_html/#!/page_brews

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the funcion that changes dinamically the content position

```
$(window).resize(function (){
    if (content)
        content.stop().animate(
           {'top':(windowH()-content.height())*.5},
           500,'easeOutCubic');
});
```

in your scripts.js

right now, it is vertically centered, try calculating a lower value (may be the easiest way is changing the .5 to say .2
Anyway, be careful not to go too up in small windows sizes