# Closing the gaps between div with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want join the breadcrumb div to the header and the left-side-bar div, the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSPGe.png) is attached.

And also I want make the content div cover the whole page - at the moment it covers up only 3/4 of the content div. (I couldn't achieve this with [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418064/closing-gap-between-divs) or Google search...)

HTML Code:

```
    <div> <!-- container -->

            <div id="header">
               <h1 align="center">Dashboard</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="nav">
                Networks<br>
                Data Management<br>
                Assets<br>
            </div>

            <div id="section">
            <div id="content-header">
                <h6 align="left">Breadcrumb</h6>
            </div>
            <h2>London</h2>
            <p>
                London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United                          Kingdom,
        with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
            </p>
            <p>
        Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia,
        its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.
            </p>

    </div>

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

CSS code:

```
    #header {
        background-color:#fecb00;
        color:white;
        text-align:center;
        padding:5px;
        }
    #nav {
       line-height:30px;
       background-color:#002244;
       color:white;
       height:819px;
       width:200px;
       float:left;
      padding:5px;
     }
    #section {
        min-height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        float:left;
       padding:10px;         
     }

    #content-header {
       background-color:#747678;
       color:white;
       text-align:center;
       padding:5px;
     }
```

Comment: You can't ask the same question twice on StackOverflow. On another note, write down your CSS/HTML/JS code in a JSFiddle or in StackOverflow Code Snippet.

Comment: Thanks @WissamEl-Kik, will put the code in JSFiddle from next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I placed your `#content-header` outside your `#section` div and that seems to solve the problem

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcx2taeh/)

This problem occurs because your `#section` div has a padding of 10 pixels, causing your breadcrumbs to move.

Comment: Thank you so much! @Azrael, it worked, once again thank you so much , have been trying since from the morning, now I got it, thanks

Comment: Haha you're welcome @Java.beginner and about that height, try doing this in your css: `calculate(100% -pixels)` where pixels would be the height of your header + breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

I took out the padding and increased the width

```css
#header {
        background-color:#fecb00;
        color:white;
        text-align:center;
        padding:5px;
        }
    #nav {
       line-height:30px;
       background-color:#002244;
       color:white;
       height:819px;
       width:200px;
       float:left;
      padding:5px;
     }
    #section {
        min-height: 100%;
        width: 84%;
        float:left;
       /*padding:10px;    */     
     }

    #content-header {
       background-color:#747678;
       color:white;
       text-align:center;
       padding:5px;
     }
```

```html
 <div> <!-- container -->

            <div id="header">
               <h1 align="center">Dashboard</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="nav">
                Networks<br>
                Data Management<br>
                Assets<br>
            </div>

            <div id="section">
            <div id="content-header">
                <h6 align="left">Breadcrumb</h6>
            </div>
            <h2>London</h2>
            <p>
                London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United                          Kingdom,
        with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.
            </p>
            <p>
        Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia,
        its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.
            </p>

    </div>

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is easy:

you can't have `width:auto` here

```
#section {
 min-height: 100%;
 width: auto;
 float:left;
 padding:10px;         
}
```

so change it either for a fixed `width` or `% width`, like this:

```
#section {
   min-height: 100%;
   width: 71%; /* adjust the width according to your needs */
   float:left;
   padding:10px;         
}
```